# use hosts on router (DD-WRT) instead of hosts in linux for homestead

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I use vagrant homestead laravel 
I used to use locally (Configure Your Nginx Sites) but i want to use it at private network (router)???
so I try to connect to router by telnet I found there is hosts file like linux hosts but after (echo multi sites) IP address and domain name inside router hosts and after reboot it, i found there is no changes (not saved)
 so what's messing 
I'm use [dd-wrt](https://secure.dd-wrt.com/site/) firmware and:
1- I use bridge so the IP diffrent from locally IP (192.168.10.10).
2- can I add domain name and IP from WEB interface.
**so the question** are it is correct way to do or there another way or some thing missing.
I use for router echo "IP1 domain name1" >>/etc/hosts 
 and "echo IP1 domain name2" >>/etc/hosts 
regards

Comment: You may want to look at [This Webpage](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=693664) as it adds some info about adding to the host file you could also do a modified version from [Here](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Ad_blocking) as this pulls the Host file off a network at boot up to block ads.

Answer (score 0):

Practically the whole filesystem under DD-WRT is decompressed from flash every boot, and not rewritable during use, other parts exist in RAM only.  You would have to rebuild a firmware file and flash it to change anything there.

Normally the only thing persistently rewritable is the NVRAM.  Only that will return upon reboot after you modify it.

[Fortunately you can write scripts to NVRAM](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Startup_Scripts) and DD-WRT will run them on boot.  Go to the Administration Tab, then Commands, then enter the commands you want to run (such as those that modify /etc/hosts), then click Save Startup.

DD-WRT does not react well if the NVRAM is overflowed so be careful not to make your scripts too long.

Comment: can i use command from telnet ?

Comment: Yep.  There's an `nvram` command that modifies nvram and you can enter scripts in the appropriate variables.  Might have to look at existing nvram vars to see how its done.  Be very careful modifying NVRAM variables from command line.

Comment: thank u for ur response,when i nslookup from router its:                             nslookup pydio.app
Server:    192.168.3.3
Address 1: 192.168.3.3 DD-WRT.app

Name:      pydio.app
Address 1: 192.168.3.10 homestead.app
-------------------------but from computer :                                                   nslookup pydio.app
Server:  127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: pydio.app
Address: 127.0.53.53
------------------ so where is the wrong ??